# php rsa sign error on linux 500 Internal Server Error . but on window is ok

Tags: php, linux, rsa, phpseclib

```
    $RSA = new \Crypt_RSA();
    $RSA->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
    $RSA->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);

    $result = $RSA->loadKey($merchantPrivateKey); ///0  391
    $query = array('a'=>12,'b'=>23);
    $sign = base64_encode($RSA->sign(join('', $query)));
    var_dump($sign);
```

sign method appear error,php error log is allowed memory size of 52222

Comment: basically, this means  your script consumes too much RAM

Comment: because your windows-server allows your scripts to consume more ram than the linux server. this can be set in php.ini

Comment: I set ram more larger in php.ini,the allowed memory size more larger.

Comment: the memory_limit is 128M

Comment: It's hard to reproduce without a copy of a key that demonstrates the problem. Can you generate a private key that you're not actually using that you'd be willing to share that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: thank you,I find the answer,the linux server is lack of bcmath extension.

Comment: It'd still be interesting to see the key. phpseclib uses it's own internal implementation when neither bcmath or gmp aren't available. It's slower and consumes more memory either bcmath or gmp but unless you key is like 20MB or some such lol I wouldn't expect an error

Comment: Hey, don't use PKCS1. [Use RSASS-PSS with MGF1-SHA256](https://github.com/paragonie/EasyRSA/blob/e979e1cfd53fcb4999e26527bf5a91d0740a5657/src/EasyRSA.php#L125-L130) instead.